# Unable to compile project with Effects11 library(VS2017)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, directx-11

I've been trying to compile my project with the Effects11 library, but I can't get it to work. I'm working on a 64bit dll.

I had Effects11 compiled with VS2013, so I tried compiling it with VS2017, but it just changed the error I get.

Error below:

```
Effects11.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu D3DCompileFromFile référencé dans la fonction D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile
```

Also, I don't use any of these functions in my project. I use D3DX11CompileFromMemory instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I took d3dcompiler.lib from the windows sdk on my windows 10 pc(the one I'm using to work on this project is on windows 7) and replaced it with the one I had on my current pc. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version of Effects 11 from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) which has been updated to work without requiring any of the legacy DirectX SDK components (i.e. `D3DX11`). It uses `D3DCompile` which is part of the Windows 8.x and Windows 10 SDKs.

> When using [VS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/03/07/visual-studio-2017/), what workloads did you install? Are you building a Win32 desktop app or a UWP app?

See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/), and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)